# Make Website Accessible Online with an IIS Server and a Static IP

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-hosting

I have a window server 2008 with an IIS 7.0 and Static IP. The website www.xyz.com (with PORT: http:80 & https:443) is running well on it. Now, I deployed another website on it using same IP address but with Port http:180. The another website is working good locally but not accessible on web.

What are next steps to make website online?

Regards,
Aman

Comment: offtopic here, move to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

That should be it.  If you can access it locally with `http://localhost:180`, then IIS is listening on the port and should be serving requests.  If you are not able to access it remotely via `http://the.site.ip.address:180`, I would suspect that a firewall somewhere is preventing connections over this non-standard port.